# The input sent from ionic to php is blank with Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 error

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework

I am doing a simple registration of user from Ionic to PHP. I just want some help from you all to put some light on the error I am facing and help me correct it.

My PostMan response is as follows:

```
[{
    "userData": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "1235467890",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "password": "7815696eascbf1c96e6894b779456fdfd33sds0e"
    }
}]
```

which is a valid json response as checked on jsonlint.com

This is my php file:

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day

    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');        



       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);

    }

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);


$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);



$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);


$sql = "select * from user where u_email like '".$email."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $code = "reg_failed";
    $message = "User Exists";
    $response = ['code' => $code, 'message' => $message];

    echo json_encode($message);
}
else
{
    $sql = "insert into user (u_name,u_num,u_email,u_pass)values ('".$name."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$password."');";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $code = "reg_success";
    $message = "Registration Success";
    $response = ['name' => $name, 'phone' => $phone, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password];
        echo '[{"userData": '.json_encode($response).'}]';

}
?>
```

This is my register.ts file

```
export class RegisterPage {

  responseData:any;
  userData = {"name":"","phone":"","email":"","password":""}

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public authService:AuthServiceProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegisterPage');
  }

  login(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
  signUp(){
      this.authService.postData(this.userData, "filename.php").then((result) =>{
        this.responseData = result; 
        console.log(this.responseData);
        localStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
        this.navCtrl.push(LocationpagePage);
      }, (err) =>{
        console.log("error", this.responseData);
      });
  }
}
```

My register.html file

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-title>Register</ion-title>
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
<ion-input type = "text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)] = "userData.name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<ion-input type = "phone" placeholder="Mobile" [(ngModel)] = "userData.phone"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<ion-input type = "email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)] = "userData.email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<ion-input type = "password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)] = "userData.password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button ion-button round color="secondary" (click)="signUp()">Register</button>
<p>Already a User?</p> <a href = "#" (click) = "login()">Sign In</a>
</ion-content>
```

And finally this is my auth-service file

```
let apiUrl = "http://url/foldername/";

/*
  Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }
    postData(credentials,type){

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.http.post(apiUrl+type,JSON.stringify(credentials),{headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json()); 
        }, (err) =>{
            reject(err);
        });
      });

    }

}
```

My console error:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (auth-service.ts:27)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

I am just trying to find the issue but i am unable to rectify. Help me find my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somehow worked when I uploaded my files and db online. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to your postman response, you have to make following changes in code

```
[(ngModel)] = "data[0].userData.name"
```

make changes in all like this fields and in typescript file

```
data = [{ 
"userData": {"name":"","phone":"","email":"","password":""}
}];

  this.authService.postData(this.data, "filename.php").then((result)
```

Comment: I tried this soution @Muhammad Rameez but I end up getting this error 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: share link of api so i can check